# 生成されないコードの原因が分かりません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

フォローした際に相手方にフォローされたことを伝える通知機能を作成しています。
フォローを生成するコントローラー(relationship_controller)が正常に動き、userのmodelにて、
通知を生成するコードに流れていくのですが、生成されませんでした。
生成箇所のコードを拝見して頂けないでしょうか？

user.rb

```
def create_notification_follow!(current_user)
      notification = current_user.active_notifications.new(
        visited_id: id,
        action: 'follow'
      )
      notification.save if notification.valid?
  end
```

relationship_controller

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:follow_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    # ここから通知機能
    user.create_notification_follow!(current_user)
    # ここまで通知機能
    flash[:success] = 'ユーザをフォローしました。'
    redirect_to user
  end
```

バージョン
Ruby on Rails6